# How to sort list using Angular Sortable and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, rubaxa-sortable

I'm stuck with this problem. I;ve built an API in Rails and a client in Angular. I've got a model called `Todo` which has a property called `order`. When I create a new Todo, I automatically assign the newly created todo a value order like so:

```
@todo = Todo.create(todo_params)
@todo.order = Todo.count + 1
```

And to display all todos:

```
@todos = Todo.where(...).order(:order.desc)
```

In my client I'm using [Sortable](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) for the UI manipulation and there's a method called `onUpdate` which gives me the new indexes for the array.

The problem I'm having is that the indexes are considerably different than the value I've in the `order` property. When the aforementioned function is called I get the item and two more values: `newIndex` and `oldIndex`, but the problem is that this doesn't give me the index of the other todos, so how can I reorganise this on the database?

I'd appreciate any help as I'm a bit at loss here.

PS: Please note this is Rails API only, so no views.

**EDIT**

**Output wanted:**

Let's imagine this: I have three items in the database: `{name: A, order: 1}, {name: B, order: 2}, {name: C, order: 3}`. In the front-end, while using ng-repeat, each item will have an `$index`. Let's say for argument sake that A will have `$index` value of 0, B 1, C 2. At the moment, when I use the Angular library Sortable, when I manually sort the list, I get the values: `oldIndex` and `newIndex` which corresponds to the position of the item I've moved within the array, but it does not shows the position of all items within array, so I don't know how to use the properties these values to update the object in the database.

Comment: You are on Rails 5 then right?

Comment: Unfortunately no (the project started before Rails 5 was released) so we're using Rails 4 and removed all the views, etc.

Comment: What really would help is some sort of output that you are expecting and the output that is currently unwanted ... What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might be interested: At the end I've used the following solution:

Every time `Sortable` updated an item, it also sends an array with all items on it in the correct order. I then looped through the array and updated each item with the new order. Not sure this is the most efficient way to do it but it resolved the problem for now.